# ion-back-button not changing direction when dir=rtl until re-rendered in ionic 5

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic, and i was trying to implement the `ion-back-button` in my `mobile-header.component`, positioning is going fine, but I'm getting a weird behavior as defined in the question's title. Here's some code:

**`mobile-header.component.html`**:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button color="standard" *ngIf="isVisible" defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{'portfolio' | translate}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-menu-button color="standard" menu="main-menu"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

First of all, i tried to manually rotating in `CSS` like this:

```
ion-back-button[dir="rtl"] {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Then I followed the issue on **[forum.ionicframework](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-i-change-the-back-button-in-header-arrow-to-the-right/91591)** and that led me to GitHub, and figured out it was there until ionic 4 was released, now afterwards, I knew it was actually solved, but not until the component itself is re-rendered.

### EDIT:

I have noticed that changing layout direction isn't actually changing the `dir` attribute for `<html>`, so I am still getting `<html dir="en">` when i inspect it.

Here's how I am changing layout direction:

**First**: I am injecting `DOCUMENT` in my `.service.ts` file like this:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document,
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) {}
```

**Second**: in corresponding `function` I am applying an explicit `doc.dir` value like this:

```
//For English (LTR)
selectEnglish() {
  this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
  this.translateService.use('en');
  this.doc.dir = 'ltr';
}

//For Arabic (RTL)
selectArabic() {
  this.translateService.setDefaultLang('ar');
  this.translateService.use('ar');
  this.doc.dir = 'rtl';
}
```

I used this method because I thought it's of the best practices, So there might be a different method for changing layout direction to solve this problem?

Here are some demo pictures:

- **Default LTR**

[image: Default LTR]

- **When RTL triggered**

[image: When RTL triggered]

- **When going to home page where no "back button" there**

[image: When going to home page where no "back button" there]

- **Finally returning back to any other component where the back button is supposed to show**

[image: component where the back button is supposed to show]

And it works again...

Here are some dependencies in my `package.json`, might want to see that too:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    ...
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `BehaviorSubject` to distribute direction value to whoever `subscribe` to it.

Here's how my `translation.service.ts` looks like now

```
export class TranslationService {
  direction: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('ltr');

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

  initLanguages() {
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translateService.addLangs(['en', 'ar']);
    this.translateService.use('en');
  }

  selectEnglish() {
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translateService.use('en');
    this.direction.next('ltr');
  }

  selectArabic() {
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('ar');
    this.translateService.use('ar');
    this.direction.next('rtl');
  }
}
```

And inside the `constructor` of my `app.component.ts`

```
this.translationService.direction.subscribe((dir) => {
      this.direction = dir;
});
```

And of course, added the `[dir]` attribute combined with `direction` value to change accordingly in my `app.component.html` like this

```
<ion-app [dir]="direction">
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

Now in my `mobile-header.component.ts` I also subscribed to the emitted value the same way i did in my `app.component.ts` like this

```
this.translationService.direction.subscribe((dir) => {
      this.isRTL = dir === 'rtl' ? true : false;
});
```

Also added a `.rtl` CSS class in my `mobile-header.component.css` like this

```
.rtl {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

*Thanks [Calummm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2450657/calummm) for this note.*

Eventually, in my `mobile-header.component.html` I ended up using `[ngClass]` on `ion-back-button` like this

```
<ion-back-button mode="md" color="standard" *ngIf="isVisible" defaultHref="/" [ngClass]="isRTL? 'rtl':''"></ion-back-button>
```

I was really looking for a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: I have the same issue but I am wondering. Won't the scaleX(-1) rotate it back to LTR once rerendered in RTL?

Comment: Since the `scaleX(-1)` is added within a CSS class scope, with the `[ngClass]="isRTL? 'rtl':''"` also added to the element then nope.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look through the documentation, it appears dynamically switching site direction is only partially supported. I would guess this is having flow on effects where an element is only updating the direction on instantiation, hence only being correct when navigating away and back.

In our application, we set the direction on the root element and inherit this via a selector. In your case selecting all ion back buttons when the direction is set.

```
html[dir="rtl"] ion-back-button {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

I noticed they supply some mixins in order to do this as well as found at: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/rtl-support/

```
@include rtl() {
  ion-back-button {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

Additionally I found it better to use a negative scaleX rather than rotating as this could potentially be useful for other icons in the future, such as magnifying glass. (Being held in the left hand)

```
transform: scaleX(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks you for the `transform: scaleX(-1);` note, but the solution you suggested is not working, and thus, there might were an `rtl` mixin in **ionic 3**, but it's not there in **ionic 5**.